# Terraform Destroy Deletes Terminate Lifecyclehook first before the hook is triggered

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

**Expected Behavior**

When resources are deployed using autoscaling group with Terminating lifecycle hook setup, Terraform destroy command should invoke/trigger the terminating lifecyclehook and wait for the instance to be terminated before the terminating lifecyclehook is destroyed.

**Actual Behavior**

When resources are deployed using autoscaling group with Terminating lifecycle hook setup, Terraform destroy command does not trigger terminatnig lifecyclehook, instead noticed that the lifecycle resource is destroyed first before autoscaing group/instances are terminated/destroyed.

**Steps to Reproduce the Problem**

Below code is used for deploying autoscaling group, with initial lifecycle hook and a separate lifecycle resouce for terminating.

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg_group" {
  count                     = var.autoscaling ? 1 : 0
  name                      = var.asg_name
  max_size                  = var.asg_max_size
  min_size                  = var.asg_min_size
  wait_for_capacity_timeout = "0"
  health_check_grace_period = var.asg_health_check_grace_period
  desired_capacity          = var.asg_desired_capacity
  launch_configuration      = var.operating_system == "rhel" ? 
  aws_launch_configuration.launch_cf[0].name : 
  aws_launch_configuration.launch_cf_windows[0].name
  vpc_zone_identifier       = local.subnet_ids
  tags = concat(local.asg_tags,local.custom_tags_format)
  timeouts {
    delete = var.asg_timeouts
  }

initial_lifecycle_hook {
    name                 = "${var.asg_name}-launching"
    default_result       = "CONTINUE"
    heartbeat_timeout    = 600
    lifecycle_transition = "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCHING"
  
}
```

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_lifecycle_hook" "terminating" {
  count = var.autoscaling ? 1 : 0
  name                   = "${var.asg_name}-terminating"
  depends_on             = [aws_autoscaling_group.asg_group]
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.asg_group[0].name
  default_result         = "CONTINUE"
  heartbeat_timeout      = 900
  lifecycle_transition   = "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATING"
  
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

**Solutions Tried:**

Tried adding depends_on in aws_autoscaling_lifecycle_hook, but did not help.

`depends_on             = [aws_autoscaling_group.asg_group]`

Comment: Is there a reason you don't have the termination lifecycle hook in the `aws_autoscaling_group` resource as an `initial_lifecycle_hook`?

Comment: Should I have it in initial_lifecycle_hook? I'm thinking it is only during launch.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR added the termination lifecycle hook in the aws_autoscaling_group resource as an initial_lifecycle_hook and it works as expected. Thank you